# how to create table of contents for thesis like the picture attached

Tags: table-of-contents

Please I want to generate a table of content just like the picture below. How do I achieve that. Need your help. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please show us what you've tried, so we have a tarting point.

Comment: That's simply the default style of some classes like `book` or `scrbook`, you can try these.